# Aligning divs correctly within a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so... I have had this issue for a long time it feels like so now I've decided to reach out and see if there is anyone else is more experienced with bootstrap than I am.

So I have these 2 divs which is within another col-12 div. These two divs are both col-6, so I want them to take up half of the space within that col-12.

I cannot get the correct padding/margin.. Either they are "stuck" to eachother and takes too much space, or they align underneeth. I've tried almost everything :(

This is how I get the code to look like right now:

[image: current code output]

This is the current code I have, without the "content". I've just placed the divs as they look basically.

```html
<div class="container-fluid wm-body trips-page">
<div class="row wm-card trips-row" style="margin: 15px 0 0 0; padding: 0px;">

 <div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">
 </div>

</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-12">     
   </div>  
  
   <div class="col-md-12 pickup-dropoff">
    <div *ngIf="trip" class="col-md-6 wm-card pickup">
    </div>  
  
    <div *ngIf="trip" class="col-md-6 wm-card dropoff">
    </div>

   </div>
   
  </div>  
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="wm-card">
  </div>
 </div>
    
</div>
</div>
```

**However... This is the outcome I want and expect.**

[image: Expected outcome]

So this is it.. I am going crazy!
Anyone knows how to do it?

**EDIT:** Well... I've tried wrapping it in its own row.. I've tried nesting it in different ways...
But now there is all of the code without its content of divs basically.

Comment: Please provide full code to find a possible solution , with this piece of code it's hard to answer the question . Please add more details and what you have tried so far

Comment: I've updated the code snippet and added some options I've tried.

Comment: Only html is not enough , post your CSS to find out more details about how you want to place the divisions and all the content

Comment: There is no css. This is it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also describe you are using Bootstrap4 next time.

I wrote a small frame that can help you going.

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}
div {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
div.col>div::after {
  content: 'Lorem Ipsum';
}
.col > div {
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-6">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Check the code @ Codepen](https://codepen.io/martinlecke/pen/MGJMeG)